# What is a good BASIC compiler for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, basic, qbasic

What is a good BASIC compiler for Windows XP?

Comment: Also, you can try QB64. Pretty much any variant of the qbasic syntax is good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also for paid, DarkBasic and BlitzBasic

Comment: 2 answers and 1 comment. You should edit your answer to include updated information. Putt additional info in a comment only if it is a response from another comment, or better yet edit the existing post.

Answer (score 1):

QBASIC. Check qbcafe

Answer (score 1):

[RealBasic](http://www.realsoftware.com/) gets good marks.  [Visual Basic](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/) is also a good basic and should work fine on XP.

Answer (score 0):

FreeBASIC

http://www.freebasic.net/index.php